# Unknown error on Google Appscript RoleAssignments

Tags: google-apps-script

i am trying to update user's role based on a CSV and decided to use App Script. Everything went well, from listing roles, getting & updating users, until inserting role assignment.

```
AdminDirectory.RoleAssignments.insert({
    roleId: ROLE_ID,
    assignedTo: data.user_id,
    scopeType: 'CUSTOMER',
    orgUnitId: ORG_UNIT_ID,
}, 'my_customer')
```

I am stuck now since the error log only show "Unknown Error"

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.roleAssignments.insert failed with error: Unknown Error.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like the error stems from the fact that you are trying to insert an assignment role which already exists.**

There is already an open issue on Google's Issue Tracker regarding this.

I suggest you star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179280366) and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.

Comment: I also thought it was because of the already added permission. I remove all permission but it still throw the same error :(

Comment: Can you confirm that you didn't insert this role assignment before for this user?